# how to validate array checkbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to validate the check box containing array name in Jquery?

1. I 've 12 checkbox with same name if all the checkbox is null i want display alert if any one field is not empty then i want to display no_error

Answer (score 0):

You can select the checkbox name, then using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate all of the checkbox that have the same name, something like this :

**Here the sample of html snippet**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skill_core[]" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="1" checked=checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="skill_core[]" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="1"/>
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{
  $('input[name^=skill_core]').each(function(i,e){

      if($(this).is(':checked'))
      {
          alert('Checked'); // here you can ignore or doing your stuff if checked
      }
      else
      {
          alert('Nope Checked'); // and here you can make styling for error indicator 
          return false;
      }
  });

});
```

You can populate above code inside submit function for validation.

**answer for validation**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#nextBtn,#opt").click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      if($('#title').val() == '')
      {
          // alert('Enter title field');
          $('#title').css("border-color","red");
          var msg="Enter the Title Field";
          $('#title').attr("placeholder",msg);
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
        $('#title').css("border-color","");      
      }

      if($('#skill').val() == '')
      {
          $('#skill').css("border-color","red");
          var skillmsg="Enter the Skill Field";
          $('#skill').attr("placeholder",skillmsg);
          return false;
      }
      else
      {

        $('#skill').css("border-color","");

      }

      $('input[name^=skill_core]').each(function(e){

        if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            alert('Nope Checked');
            return false;
        }
      });

      if($('#location').val() == '')
      {
          $('#location').css("border-color","red");
          var lmsg="Enter the Location Field";
          $('#location').attr("placeholder",lmsg);
          return false;
      }
      else
      {
          $('#location').css("border-color","");
      }

      if(('#rang').val()=="")
      {
          alert('value');
          return false;
      }



  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you code is working but i need without function is it possible

Comment: What you mean without function. can you tell more about your requirement.

Comment: I already created function in that function only iam going to write the script but if i merge the above function with the existing function "return false" is not working.

Comment: Then post your function. Wanna see that, easy for me to attach above code.

Comment: After displaying 'Nope checked' i don't want to move next page.

Comment: i paste it in answer field plz check that.

Comment: It not good to post the question in answer section. Remove that and paste into your question(paste together with html code). And see edited posted. Try that one.

Comment: You have working fiddle?? It so hard to debug with the length of code and without working example.

Comment: sorry for my approach to Norlihazmey Ghazali, I 've one doubt <input type="checkbox" name="skill_core[]" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" value="1"/>like this i 've 12 check boxes with same name . I want  to check all the field if any one field contain value means i don't want to show alert . If all the field is empty then ly it ll show error msg how to do this

Comment: so, you did't want checked or not. Overall you just want any checkbox have value or not, then show alert if no value for all 12 checkbox. lika that??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73646/discussion-between-m-athish-krishna-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).